# SwiftUI: Sending preference key when publisher/binding emits value

Tags: swiftui

I have a situation where I have a view model with a `@Published` value. Now when I'm building the UI I want to send a value via a preference every time the published value changes. The problem I'm having is that I cannot figure out how to get SwiftUI to watch the published value and send the preference.

In the code below I've endeavoured to simplify the problem.

Preference key:

```swift
struct NewValueKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: String? = nil
    static func reduce(value: inout String?, nextValue: () -> String) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
```

Publishing object:

```swift
public class SomeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var value: String?
}
```

And in the Swift UI view:

```swift
.onReceive(viewModel.$value) { _ in
    let newValue = "abc"
    Color.clear.preference(key: NewValueKey.self, value: newValue)
}
```

But I get a variety of errors such as the result of the preference not being used, etc. The problem is that I need to execute some code to build the value I want to send so I can't just forward the value I receive. I've also looked at using a `@State` property as some sort of intermediary but I'm not sure how to wire it all together.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to inject `value` directly into `preference` modifier attached to a view within modified context (ie. you don't need `.onReceive` modifer because updated value will activate `.preference` modifier directly).

Tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

Here is a snapshot of main part

```
Button("Generate") {
    vm.value = String(Int.random(in: 0...9))
}
.preference(key: NewValueKey.self, value: vm.value)  // << here !!
```

Completed [findings report and code is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/Answers/ViewModel_via_ViewPreferences.md)

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, the .preference(key:value:) function does watch the value and send a preference update when it changes? The doco is a little light and I wasn't sure if that was the case, Helen why I was exploring other options.

Comment: A SwiftUI `View` observes changes of a dynamic property (in this case from VM) and refreshes `body` injecting new value wherever that property is located (either it is `Text`, or `.preference`, or any other element or modifier).

Answer (score 0):

not clear what you want, but ensure that you have something like this in your view, or equivalent `@ObservedObject`:

```
    @StateObject var viewModel = SomeViewModel()
```

Also:

```
struct NewValueKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: String = ""  // <-- here

    static func reduce(value: inout String, nextValue: () -> String) { // <-- here
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
```

and to get rid of the warning:

```
    .onReceive(viewModel.$value) { _ in
        let newValue = "abc"
        let _ = Color.clear.preference(key: NewValueKey.self, value: newValue) // <-- here
    }
```

or

```
    .onReceive(viewModel.$value) { val in
        if let newValue = val {
            let _ = Color.clear.preference(key: NewValueKey.self, value: newValue) // <-- here
        }
    }
```